# The limit is independent of the order of summation if the series converges absolutely?

Tags: calculus, analysis, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to find an explanation and an example that proves that if the series converges absolutely, then the limit is independent of the order of summation.

If anyone can help with this one I would be very grateful!

Comment: $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32.......$ is absolute convergent. The sum equals $1$. Changing the order of summation has no effect on the outcome.